# Make Table column cells match column title

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering how would I figure to make my table cells match the table th (header) in order to align them properly.

In other words, how to make  "Justificatif d'immatriculation" go under  "Justificatif d'immatriculation" as example, or  "Attestation de vigilance" go under "Attestation de vigilance" 
[Screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi26W.png)

Many thanks !

Comment: You will need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get the help you are looking for (we can't tell what is happening from an image link).

Comment: Actually I have something like this:

CompanyName    |  Red   |  Blue |  Yellow
company1               Blue      Yellow   Red


And what I want to do dynamically (jquery/js) is to have this:

CompanyName    |  Red   |  Blue |  Yellow
company1               Red      Blue    Yellow

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

did you try with the textproperty `textAlign: 'left'` by the headers textElements?